# Disable tableau custom view / remember my changes

Tags: tableau-api

I want to disable the **"Remember my changes**" or the **custom views** options on a tableau view.

I know it can be disabled by using ":CustomViews=n" parameter on the URL. But i want to disable it from server level.

If possible, i would also want to disable it for certain users only.

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to disable custom views in Tableau Server.

[As a workaround, site administrators and other authorized users can allow or deny the permission 'Share Customized' which allows saved customizations to a view available for others to see.](http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/current/online/en-us/adminview_custom.htm)