# Tableau disable custom view option

Tags: tableau-api

Is it possible to disable the custom view option in Tableau? And if yes, how do can I do that?

In 2014 the same question was [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26993979/disable-tableau-custom-view-remember-my-changes). Then it was not possible, but maybe now it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching through Tableau Server's online help guide yields no results for the ability to disable Custom Views. I also, just in case, double checked the TabAdmin and TSM commands lists - neither of which has a command relating to Custom Views.

However, there looks to be an "idea" on the [Tableau Ideas Forum](https://community.tableau.com/ideas/8959) which you may want to vote up. This "idea" in particular is requesting a permission, but you can create one for a server-wide system setting in that Ideas Forum as well.